# No find(element) method in vectors

Tags: c++

I was just looking through stl and noticed that C++ vectors do not have a `find(givenElement)` type of method. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: One of the goals the STL was to avoid having to implement every relevant algorithm separately for every container. That leads to M*N algorithms where M is the number of basic algorithms and N is the number of containers you implement each one for. The way the STL achieved this 'strength reduction' was to implement algorithms as _non-member functions_ using templates and 'generic programming.' Many algorithms, including find on vector, will not be found as methods on a container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`std::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) instead.

```
std::vector<int> x;
//...
std::find(x.begin(),x.end(),42);
```

*Note* that if you have multiple elements of the same value, you only get the first one (but you can change the start iterator accordingly).

Sample http://ideone.com/JADSl

Answer (score 1):

Note also that `std::find` does NOT return `true` or `false`. It returns an iterator to the position at which the element was found. eg.

```
if ( std::find( x.begin(), x.end(), 42 ) == x.end() )
{
    // We get here if 42 is not found in the vector!!
}
```